# C++ Getting input from txt file for SIR Model

Tags: c++, vector, ifstream

I am having some trouble with a school project of mine so I would like help getting to a solution instead of someone just posting one. Let's say an input file (input1.txt) would look like this:

```
Threshold:1
Infectious Period:2
Display:2

s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,i,i,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,i,i,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s,s
```

I have to get the Threshold, Infectious Period, and Display and store them somewhere and have an array/vector store the rest. I thought the best approach would be to copy the file to a temporary one and then use it to create a vector. I managed to create the vector but am having trouble grabbing the values I need. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> civs;
std::string fileName;
std::ifstream input;
int susceptible = 0;
int infectious = 0;
int recovered = 0;
int vaccinated = 0;
int days = 0;

void getFile()
{
    std::string fileName;
    std::string line;

    std::cout << "Input the file name: "; // Gets the file from the user
    std::cin >> fileName;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    const char *Fname = fileName.c_str();

    std::ifstream iFile; //Input output file stream objects
    std::ofstream oFile;

    iFile.open(Fname); //Opens the user's set input file

    if (iFile.fail()) //Checks for an error in opening file then exits program after giving error message
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
    }

    oFile.open("tempFile.txt"); //Opens temporary interim file to process incoming data

    while (std::getline(iFile, line, ',')) //Writes out all values separated by ',', leaving all int. Values are left in even numbered lines
    {
        oFile << line << std::endl;
    }

    oFile.close();
    iFile.close();
}

int main()
{

    getFile();

    std::ifstream iFile; //Input output file stream objects
    std::ofstream oFile;
    std::string line;

    iFile.open("tempFile.txt");

    int lineCount = 0; //Counter used to ensure only even lines are saved into vector

    std::vector <std::string> tempStrings;

    while (std::getline(iFile, line, ',')) //Places all lines that contain data (even lines) into a string vector for later processing
    {
        tempStrings.push_back(line);
        lineCount++;
    }

    iFile.close();

    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = tempStrings.begin(); iter != tempStrings.end(); ++iter)
        std::cout << *iter << ' ';

    return 0;
}
```

It creates the temporary file right but the vectors first element (tempStrings[0]) comes out to be:

```
Threshold:1
Infectious Period:2
Display:2

s
```

Am I just going about this the wrong way? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this? There is still a lot more to do with the project and I'm stuck on step 1.

Comment: `std::getline(iFile, line, ',')` is specifying that your lines are delimited by a comma.  If you want them to be delimited by a newline, then use `std::getline(iFile, line)`.

Comment: That works when creating the vector. You're awesome, thank you.

Comment: I don't see the need to copy the data from one file into another and then read that file, like you're doing here.  Seems like you've decided that's a solution to some other problem you're having.  I suggest simplifying.  It only requires a few lines of code to read and parse all the data.